# How to implement Depth first search using adjacency list for character or string data type

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph, depth-first-search

for integer, I did this but when I tried for strings or character I failed.
I want to apply this same code for string or character but only want to add DFS function in this.
if we call addedge(1,2) then it will add 2 in 1's list and 1 in 2's list.

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};
struct Vnode
{   
        struct node *head;
        int visited;
};
class graph
{
    public:
    int n;
    struct Vnode *Vertex;
    graph(int n)
    {
        this->n=n;
        Vertex = new Vnode[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            Vertex[i].head=NULL;
            Vertex[i].visited=0;
        }
    }
    void addEdge(int startp,int endp)
    {    

        node *newnode = new node();   
        newnode->data=endp;
        newnode->next=Vertex[startp].head;
        Vertex[startp].head=newnode;
        node *newnode1 = new node();
        newnode1->data=startp;
        newnode1->next=Vertex[endp].head;
        Vertex[endp].head=newnode1;
    }

   void DFS(int index)
    {
    cout<<index<<" ";
    Vertex[index].visited=1;
    node *newnode=Vertex[index].head;
    while(newnode!=NULL)
    {
        if(Vertex[newnode->data].visited==1)
        {
            newnode=newnode->next;
        }
        else
        {
            DFS(newnode->data);
            newnode=newnode->next;
        }
    }
    }
};
```

Comment: So you want to perform DFS  on graphs whose nodes contain string or character data values ?

Comment: yes @GAURANGVYAS

Comment: One thing that could be done is that you can map every string or character to some integer value.

Comment: How ? @GAURANGVYAS

Comment: Moreover, since this question is having C++ tag, the above  implementation can be modified to make use of C++ STL. Instead of maintaining a linked list like structure for edges. You can use C++ vectors.

Comment: What if there is the string then how to change it into an integer?

Comment: Yes I know about vector implementation

Comment: But you told about mapping.How to do that.I understand for character you can do in any way bu what for string?

Comment: Consider the node values - "abc", "def", "ghi". Now you can use C++ map data structure. to give  value 1 to string "abc" ," 2 to "def" ... .Surely this will increase the complexity of getting the integer value of a string.

Comment: You mean time complexity? @GAURANGVYAS

Comment: so I have to create a reference of given string? @GAURANGVYAS

Comment: Time complexity is increased. Each time you use map data structure. It take log(n) time to get the required value.